# NIntegrate fails to finish evaluating

Tags: numerical-integration

I am performing a numerial integration of a function commonly found in subsurface flow problems for oil/gas:

`2*NIntegrate[ x/(Ug[x, zGasTemp[x]]*ZGasTemp[x]), {x, 0, 200}]`

where Ug and ZGasTemp are high order polynomical functions, and ZGasTemp is solved numerically as a function of p.  **Ug is solved directly but is a function of ZGasTemp as well as x**.

Using simple manual code for integration I have:

```
mp[p_, temp_, SG_, n2_, co2_, h2s_] := Module[
      {mpSolution = 0, Pold = 0, Xold = 0, Xnew = 0, Step = 20, 
   
Pstep = 0, Pnew = 0, zg},
          
      Pstep = p / Step;
      Do[
           Pnew = Pold + Pstep;
           zg = ZGasTemp[Pnew, temp, SG, n2, co2, h2s];
           Xnew = 2 * Pnew /  zg / Ug[Pnew, temp, SG, zg];
           mpSolution = mpSolution + (Xold + Xnew) / 2 * Pstep;
           Pold = Pnew;
           Xold = Xnew;
           ,
        {20}];
      mpSolution
  ]
```

The function evaluates reasonably well and compares to publised values. For instance:

mp[200, 120, 0.65, 0, 0, 0] = 3.43687 x 10^6

If I use NIntegrate, as shown below, the function never finishes evaluating:

```
mpWolfram[p_, temp_, SG_, n2_, co2_, h2s_] := 
NIntegrate[2 x/
        (ZGasTemp[x, temp, SG, n2, co2, h2s]*
              Ug[x, temp, SG, ZGasTemp[x, temp, SG, n2, co2, h2s]]),
        {x, 0, p},
        Method -> "TrapezoidalRule", MaxPoints -> 12, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

mpWolfram[200, 120, 0.65, 0, 0, 0] = NEVER FINISHES COMPUTATION

My guess is the problem relies on the fact that Ug[x] is also dependent upon ZGasTemp[x].

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It finishes real quick for me, but that's because I don't have definitions for `Ug[]` or `ZGasTemp[]`.  I don't think I can help without them. Except to say I'd be surprised if `"TrapezoidalRule"` is a good choice here. (`zGasTemp` is a typo?)

Comment: Hi @MichaelE2  we can provide a link to the mathematica file if you are so inclined. The supplementary functions are Ug[x] and ZGasTemp[x] and a few others are a bit larger than a regular post

Comment: Hi, I'll be traveling tomorrow and the next day. I might have time or it might take a couple of days before I can get to it. There are others on the site who could probably help and might beat me to it. Without the code, you probably won't get help, except maybe slightly off-target generic advice, like, "Use a different method," or, "Maybe the numerical noise is causing the error estimates to blow up," and so forth.